# Creating a subset of vendor files using Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm currently working on a website with multiple pages and would like to generate JS-files using Webpack.
The scenario below is a simplified example to make it more clear what I want to achieve.

Note: in this example, a vendor-file is a library which is present in the `node_modules` directory.

**Structure**

*Page A*

- jquery.js (vendor shared between all pages)
- lodash.js (vendor shared between all pages)
- react.js (vendor specific for page A and B)
- page-a.js

*Page B*

- jquery.js (vendor shared between all pages)
- lodash.js (vendor shared between all pages)
- react.js (vendor specific for page A and B)
- page-b.js

*Page C*

- jquery.js (vendor shared between all pages)
- lodash.js (vendor shared between all pages)
- page-c.js

**Desired output**

*Page A*

- vendors-page-ab.js
- page-a.js

*Page B*

- vendors-page-ab.js
- page-b.js

*Page C*

- vendors-page-c.js
- page-c.js

I'm struggeling to come up with a Wepack configuration that is able to create a vendors file and a file containing a subset of the vendors.

What I've tried is to use the `splitChunks` optimization. But somehow, I'm unable to make a distinction between all vendors and the shared vendors using this configuration.

```
const config = {
    optimization: {
                splitChunks: {
                    cacheGroups: {
                        commons: {
                            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                            name: 'vendor',
                            chunks: 'all'
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired output structure using Webpack?

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd like to code split along routes and have different vendor bundles for each route?

Comment: I remember I achieved similar results with this tutorial, https://jes.al/2018/04/optimizing-front-end-delivery-with-Webpack-4/. The key was using dynamic imports in the app code and chunkhashes in the Webpack config.

Comment: I'd like to separate vendor bundles based on which pages they are used. See the structure and desired output, I think that gives the best idea of what I'm trying to achieve